# Sharepoint designer is not responding

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to edit a page in share point 2013 but it freezes and share point designer is not responding for several times and I tried many ways like uninstall and install share point designer, install update for it... but it didn't work

Why it happened?

Comment: try http://sympmarc.com/2013/04/16/sharepoint-designer-2013-crashing-on-open-site-the-fix/

Comment: Thank you Varun I read this link but I did not get the mean of it :( what should I exactly do?

Comment: you need to delete those registry entries as explained in the post. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows server 2012

Comment: try to delete those registry keys as shown in post and restart the server

Comment: My 14 folder in regedtit designer doesn't have findopen folder in setting

Comment: Then this is not the solution for you, as the scenario on the blog post was SPD updated from 2010 to 2013.

Comment: is this behaviour for one page or for complete site? did you try different site collection? may be you site is corrupted.

Comment: Can you correctly reach the SharePoint webservice wsdl? I had problems on the web.config file so I couldn't use the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems, in my case due to problematic display drivers.

Updating the drivers to the latest version didn't do any good, but through my troubleshoot process I found the following:

- SPD is tightly coupled with Internet Explorer. In my case, I could only open it by going to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Properties > Enable `Use software rendering instead of CPU rendering`
- Office 2010 and 2013 have known conflicting issues, so you may want to repair the setup for the one that is malfunctioning
- You can run SharePoint Designer in safe mode by adding the parameter `/safe` either in a command-line call or adding it to the shortcut

The last one appears to be the really relevant step.

[Limitations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010140792.aspx) apply using safe mode.

> In Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer, the last used Web site is not
>   opened.